# Android activity design with layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to create Android activity which looks like this:

[image]

Now I've created only such part of the activity.

[image]

Which coded this way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.alexeyzhulin.elecomp.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/logoButton"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_icon" />

                <SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/searchText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:queryHint="@string/search_message"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/cartButton"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/cart_icon1" />
            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please help me how to put last four buttons to the activity.

The particular question is:

How to put four buttons in the center of the screen.

Comment: use Constraint or Relative layout to align four button like this

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: you might want to take a look at the [GridView](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridview-vs-gridlayout-example-tutorial/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to put a sample code for you. This code can give you idea how to place four button at center of activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   //I changed it to wrap_content
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/logoButton"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            />

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:queryHint="assss"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cartButton"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
           />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/b1"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:text="button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b4"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:text="button" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey @Alex, Does it helpful

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this solution bit late. Please suggest me where I have to put RelativeLayout? Inside my "vertical" LinearLayout or inside "horizontal" LinearLayout or beneath of it?

Comment: @AlexZhulin I have modifies it can you try it once

Answer (score 1):

Just use this on the top Linear Layout

```
gravity="center"
```

OR....

```
 <ImageButton
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:id="@+id/logoButton"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_icon" />
```

If this doesnt work try to do this : Nest 2 ImageViews inside 1 LinearLayout
and create 2 Linear Layouts with weight = 1

Code :

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/logoButton"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_weight = "1"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_icon" />

                <SearchView
                    android:layout_weight = "1"
                    android:id="@+id/searchText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:queryHint="@string/search_message"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this kind of layout using **Table layout** , I recommend you to look into these links [1](http://androidexample.com/Table_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=74) ,  [2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html)(android documentation) , [3](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_table_layout.htm) for table layout tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your vertical linear layout you can give 2 more linear layouts with horizontal orientation and also with weightsum =2. Inside both these two linear layouts add 2 more linear layouts with weight =1.Give apropriate paddings for peoper button looks and then you can give the click action to the layouts.